# PyQt 5 - Pop Up Window Flashes before Closing

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to create a pop up window upon the click of a Qpushbutton.

Upon pressing the pushbutton, a window flashes on my screen, but disappears quickly thereafter. I have tried playing with adding a sys.exit(app.exec_()) statement in the function (proceed_new_table in code snip below) that creates the pop up screen, but the results are not as I desire.

Any ideas on how to make this pop-up screen stay permanently?

Code below:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QWidget, QAction, QTableWidget,QTableWidgetItem,QVBoxLayout,QPushButton, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, pyqtSlot, QSize

# this routine creates the table widget, it only appears due to being called below
class TableView(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, z, vert, *args):
        QTableWidget.__init__(self, *args)
        self.z = z
        self.setz()
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(800, 400))  # Set sizes
        self.setWindowTitle('General Spandrel Information Form')  # Set the window title
        # self.resizeColumnsToContents()
        # self.resizeRowsToContents()
        self.setVerticalHeaderLabels(vert)
    def setz(self):
        horHeaders = []
        for n, key in enumerate(sorted(self.z.keys())):
            horHeaders.append(key)
            for m, item in enumerate(self.z[key]):
                newitem = QTableWidgetItem(item)
                self.setItem(m, n, newitem)
        self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(horHeaders)

#pulls the create new table function
    def proceed_new_table(self):
        exPopup = ExampleTable_button_push()
        #exPopup.setGeometry(600, 400, 400, 400)
        exPopup.show()
        #sys.exit(app.exec_())

# this routine creates the button widget, it only appears due to being called below
class Buttons(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QPushButton.__init__(self, *args)
        okButton = QPushButton("OK",self)
        okButton.setToolTip('Press after inputting all values in table')
        #this is the on_event trigger
        okButton.clicked.connect(self.on_click)
    #the on_click function pulls the classs of 
    def on_click(self):
        TableView.proceed_new_table(self)




#this is what happens if the button is pushed
class ExampleTable_button_push(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self,*args):
        QPushButton.__init__(self, *args)
        okButton = QPushButton("OK",self)
        okButton.setToolTip('Press after inputting all values in table')



#this is the main window function
def main(args):
    app = QApplication(args)
    table = TableView(z, vert, 4, 4)
    button = Buttons()
    table.setCellWidget(3,0,button)    
    table.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

z={'a':[2,2,2],'b':[3,3,3],'c':[4,4,4]}
vert = ["Line 1","Line 2", "Line 3"]



if __name__ == '__main__':
    #main(sys.argv)
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = main(sys.argv)
    #sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t understand what you want to do, but try the example below.
I noted the lines in which I made changes.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QWidget, QAction, QTableWidget,QTableWidgetItem,QVBoxLayout,QPushButton, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, pyqtSlot, QSize

# this routine creates the table widget, it only appears due to being called below
class TableView(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, z, vert, *args):
        QTableWidget.__init__(self, *args)
        self.z = z
        self.setz()
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(800, 400))  
        self.setWindowTitle('General Spandrel Information Form')  
        self.setVerticalHeaderLabels(vert)

        button = Buttons(self)                                        # +++
        self.setCellWidget(3, 0, button)                              # +++          

    def setz(self):
        horHeaders = []
        for n, key in enumerate(sorted(self.z.keys())):
            horHeaders.append(key)
            for m, item in enumerate(self.z[key]):
                newitem = QTableWidgetItem(item)
                self.setItem(m, n, newitem)
        self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(horHeaders)

#pulls the create new table function
    def proceed_new_table(self):
        self.exPopup = ExampleTable_button_push()                     # + self
        #exPopup.setGeometry(600, 400, 400, 400)
        self.exPopup.show()                                           # + self

# this routine creates the button widget, it only appears due to being called below
class Buttons(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QPushButton.__init__(self, *args)
        self.parent = args[0]                                          # +++

        okButton = QPushButton("OK", self)
        okButton.setToolTip('Press after inputting all values in table')
        #this is the on_event trigger
        okButton.clicked.connect(self.on_click)

    #the on_click function pulls the classs of 
    def on_click(self):
#        TableView.proceed_new_table(self)
        self.parent.proceed_new_table()                                # +++



#this is what happens if the button is pushed
class ExampleTable_button_push(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self,*args):
        QPushButton.__init__(self, *args)
        okButton = QPushButton("OK",self)
        okButton.setToolTip('Press after inputting all values in table')



z    = {'a':[2,2,2],'b':[3,3,3],'c':[4,4,4]}
vert = ["Line 1","Line 2", "Line 3"]

#this is the main window function
#def main(args):
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    table = TableView(z, vert, 4, 4)
#    button = Buttons()
#    table.setCellWidget(3, 0, button)    
    table.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`okButton` has no reference outside of `Buttons.__init__` so the garbage collecting is destroying it.
You could try to keep a ref, for example as `self.okButton`